Can I take a non-folding recumbent trike on a plane
Can I take a non-folding recumbent trike such as a Catrike Expedition or 700 or HP Velotechnik Scorpion FS on an airplane via United, Delta, or American Airlines?
Those trikes weigh in around 35 lbs each and are quite bulky for the non-folding kind.  I am aware both manufacturers make folding trikes and would imagine those would be less of an issue, but am only concerned with the non-folding trikes only.

This may depend on the airline -- do you have a sense of which airline you might want to use?

You should contact various airlines. And it may be considered "cargo" so you may need to deliver the day before (and you get the information on packaging it). But it depends on a lot of variable, and we are not sending so many such item to have good information. Note: it depends on airlines, and itinerary (e.g. size of aircraft)

The answer will depend upon the size and weight of the bike, the particular aircraft on the particular flight, and the specific rules of the airline(s) involved.  The result may also depend upon the type of ticket you hold, or perhaps even your status with the airline. There are too many variables for there to be a general answer. I voted to close as "needs focus."

A quick Google search also pulls up several blog posts about people's experiences bringing recumbent bikes as baggage. It appears to be rather idiosyncratic by airline, but it seems that people have been able to do it. Calling the airline would be a good place to start for sure.

Do you fall in any category of handicapped and therefore needing the trike? If so, airlines might have a special rate, subsidised maybe.

What do you mean, disabled?  In terms of the traditional meaning, no.  I've come across https://www.youtube.com/@JaYoeNation/videos and I believe he says it is a mobility device and leaves it at that and airlines have been able to accommodate, but beyond that for packing, I haven't a clue.  I would imagine the typical stuff still applies, airlines accept no liability, etc.

I mean would you be in a wheelchair part of the time or get help from the airline for not being able to board the plane in a normal way? If so, mention it to the airline and ask them to transport the trike.

If you intend to travel with the trike more than once, folding trikes are really the best option and even those are quite bulky. They do come in very sturdy.
